# Como enviar uma requisição post utilizando axios e Asp.net Core Web API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, axios

Estou fazendo uma requisição com `axios` com o verbo `post`, mas não estou conseguindo.

Nota> Com o verbo `get` consigo fazer a requisição.

## Object

```
cliente: {
    nomeCompleto: '',
    cpf: '',
    email: '',
    endereco: {
        cep: '',
        logradouro: '',
        localidade: '',
        bairro: '',
        uf: ''
    }
}
```

## Request

```
axios.post('http://localhost:62748/api/cliente', this.cliente)
  .then(response => {
      console.log(response)
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error)
  })
```

## API

```
 [HttpPost]
 public void Post(
  [FromBody] Cliente cliente, [FromServices] ClienteRepository _repository) {
  _repository.Add(cliente);
 }
```

## Cliente Entidade

```
public int ClienteId {
 get;
 set;
}
public string Cpf {
 get;
 set;
}
public string NomeCompleto {
 get;
 set;
}
public string Email {
 get;
 set;
}
public Endereco Endereco {
 get;
 set;
}
```

## Endereco Entidade

```
   public int EnderecoId {
   get;
   set;
  }
  public string Cep {
   get;
   set;
  }
  public string Uf {
   get;
   set;
  }
  public string Localidade {
   get;
   set;
  }
  public string Bairro {
   get;
   set;
  }
  public string Logradouro {
   get;
   set;
  }
```

## Allow-Control-Allow-Origin in `Startup.cs` and `Configure`

```
services.AddCors();

app.UseCors(builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:8080"));
```

## Error

> Failed to load http://localhost:62748/api/cliente: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Comment: SOpt colega! Traduz aê!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao que parece seu JS está correto, mas você precisa habilitar o `CORS` na sua aplicação `.NET Core`, na sua classe `Startup`, no método `ConfigureServices`, adicione:

```
 services.AddCors(setup => {
  setup.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder => {
   builder.AllowAnyHeader();
   builder.AllowAnyMethod();
   builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:8080");
  });
 });

 services.Configure < MvcOptions > (options => {
  options.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory("CorsPolicy"));
 });
```

`Nota:` É importante salientar que essa política vai liberar todos os métodos para todos os `controllers`, e isso é uma brecha de segurança, você deve alterar isso para deixar mais específico quando for liberar para produção.

Fonte: [Habilitar solicitações entre origens (CORS) no núcleo do ASP.NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.1#enabling-cors-with-middleware)

Comment: Hahaha não tinha visto isso na documentação, mas era isso mesmo :)

Comment: Sabe me explicar porque com o verbo `get` eu consigo fazer uma requisição?

Comment: Se não me engano quando você adiciona o CORS com uma origem, por default ele libera o GET, visto que é um verbo de consulta. Mas para POST, PUT, DELETE ele bloqueia, pois no padrão RESTful, são métodos que alteram o estado de algo.