# Problema em chamada de api no React JS

Tags: javascript, api, asp.net-web-api, react, react-dom

Eu criei uma webapi em ASP.NET Core, e preciso consumi-la usando o React, a Web api funciona normalmente, se eu usar o curl ou Postman entre outros, ela funciona normalmente. O problema começa quando vou usar o React, quando tento fazer qualquer requisição para minha API com js da problema.

Para complicar mais ainda, quando eu faço a requisição para outras API's funciona normalmente, isso me levou a crer que o problema era na minha API porém como falei ela funciona com os outros só com o react que não. Já tentei de muitas formas.

A API está rodando em um IIS na minha rede local

### Maneiras Tentadas

### Usando Ajax

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: 'http://192.168.0.19:5200/api/token',
    beforeSend: function(xhr){
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    },
    data: {
      nome: 'nome',
      senha: 'senha'
    },
    success: function (message) {
        console.log(message);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        /*if (error.responseJSON.modelState)                                
            showValidationMessages(error.responseJSON.modelState);*/
            console.log(error);    
    }
  });
```

### Usando Fetch

```
const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    const options = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers,
      body: JSON.stringify(login),
      mode: 'cors' //Tentei com cors e no-cors
    }

    const request = new Request('http://192.168.0.19:5200/api/token', options);
    const response = await fetch(request);
    const status = await response.status;     
    console.log(response);*/
    // POST adds a random id to the object sent
    fetch('http://192.168.0.19:5200/api/token', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      nome: 'nome',
      senha: 'senha'
     }),
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    },
    credentials: 'same-origin'
    })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))
```

### Usando Request

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', 'http://192.168.0.19:5200/api/token', true);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    request.send(login);
```

### ERROS

**Console**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Aba Network (Requisições)**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Quando eu faço sem ser mudar o content type para JSON funciona, pois a API retorna dizendo que não é um tipo válido.

Comment: Qual a tecnologia de back-end vc usa? É preciso configurar o CORS no `back-end` para que seja aceitas requisições de outros domínios.

Comment: Dá uma olhada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/312129/como-enviar-uma-requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-post-utilizando-axios-e-asp-net-core-web-api

Comment: Se você puder anexar o seu código por favor, é possível que eu habilite o cors para você. Além disso, para trabalhar com chamadas a API, a comunidade React usa bastante o Axios (https://github.com/axios/axios)

Answer (score -1):

Isso é um problema muito comum com APIs.
Normalmente esse problema está relacionado a CORS, é um problema no backend.

O postman, Insomnia e outros softwares de testes de Apis acabam funcionando porém quando vai consumir a API por um frontend ocorre esses erros.

Começe a pesquisar por "core problemas call apis with reactjs"

Esse link cita algumas situações:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/fetching-data-using-web-api-in-react/