# Preciso ter um servidor para fazer um sistema de login com o react?

Tags: node.js, react, login

Pode ser uma questão boba mas estou bem confuso sobre o React.js, eu desenvolvi uma Webapi em Asp.net core e já está funcionando... Preciso fazer um sistema de login no React. Pensando na forma que eu desenvolveria, no caso programo em php, eu usaria o php para consumir essa web api.
Porém estou confuso sobre o React, eu necessito usar o node para consumir a minha web api? ou só o react já faz isso? Ah claro, lembrando que isso é para um sistema de login.

E outra pergunta, voltando no php, eu criaria um sistema de SESSION para o usuário navegar, e no caso isso ficaria no lado servidor, então me faz me q, como isso seria feito em React?

Aqui uma imagem de exemplo, de como funciona no php

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4):

Existe algumas maneiras de solucionar isso amigo, vamos por partes.

## Requisições

---

O *ReactJS* é apenas uma biblioteca para construção de interface, não te oferece, assim como *frameworks* maneiras de requisição nativa, você pode utilizar de outras bibliotecas como [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios), ou até mesmo utilizar a api [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) presente no ES6, ou até mesmo do velho *XMLHttpRequest*.

#### Exemplo com axios:

```
import React from 'react';

import axios from 'axios';

export default class PersonList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    persons: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
      .then(res => {
        const persons = res.data;
        this.setState({ persons });
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        { this.state.persons.map(person => <li>{person.name}</li>)}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}
```

#### Exemplo com fetch:

```
import React from 'react';

import axios from 'axios';

export default class PersonList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    persons: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
     fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
         .then((resp) => resp.json())
           .then(function(data) {
             const persons = res.data;
             this.setState({ persons });
          })
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        { this.state.persons.map(person => <li>{person.name}</li>)}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}
```

[Fonte](https://alligator.io/react/axios-react/)

## Sessões

#### Formas de manter o usuário logado

---

Essa vai depender mais de sua arquitetura, hoje em dia há uma tendência maior para a utilização de JWT's (JSON Web Token), onde você armazena um token gerado em sua aplicação *backend* e os envia como cabeçalho em requisições para rotas que estão protegidas, (Basicamente um sistema de crachá WEB).

A armazenação desse token pode ser feita por meio da API *WebStorage*, `sessionStorage` ou `localStorage`. 
Para manter a segurança é sempre importante dar uma olhada em como armazenar estes tokens de forma segura, implementando tokens de sincronização por exemplo, aconselho dar uma lida neste artigo https://auth0.com/docs/security/store-tokens e nesse https://medium.com/tableless/entendendo-tokens-jwt-json-web-token-413c6d1397f6.

Você pode variar o tipo de implementação com outras bibliotecas
, temos também a `redux-react-session`, nesse caso vai depender do seu ambiente.

O *reactjs* é bem agnóstico desse tipo de coisa, você pode procurar e testar a melhor estratégia que se encaixe ao que você precise.

Comment: Opa @MSLacerda, muito obrigado pela resposta. Vamos lá, eu criei já a autenticação por token, usando o JWT até ai beleza, o meu problema é o seguinte, se eu usar o axios ou fetch eu tenho alguns erros, decorrente de CORS, porém se eu faço a requisição usando o node funciona normal. Entretanto, se eu por exemplo vi que o usuário é quem alega ser, cada página que ele for acessar eu tenho que verificar denovo? Isso que me deixa em dúvida, pois com session você armazena aquele login feito por ele

Comment: Qual o erro? pode colocar na sua pergunta? Você pode verificar se existe alguém logado e também pode verificar a autenticidade daquele token em questão sempre que o usuário entrar em uma nova página ou fizer uma requisição vai depender do quão seguro você quer que sua aplicação fique.

Comment: O erro já tenho uma pergunta feita aqui, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/334219/problema-em-chamada-de-api-no-react-js, eu vou adicionar uma imagem acho que vai ficar mais claro oque estou querendo dizer